# Can electric furnaces be used for steel production from ore?

Tags: steel, metallurgy

The transition towards climate neutrality is a big political topic in Germany. One claim that is often made but typically only handwaivingly explained (if at all) is that we need (green) hydrogen.

I do understand that some processes might need hydrogen. And that hydrogen should be produced in a climate-neutral way.

But are there processes that currently use e.g. fossil gas which can/should be replaced with hydrogen?

The main example I found is **steel production**. However, I see that electric arc furnace (EAF) and induction furnace exist. My guess is that they are well-suited for scrap metal, but not for ore. Is that guess right?

If so, why are they not suited for ore? Or is it just the case that gas is so much cheaper than electricity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's almost certainly true that an electric arc furnace isn't adequate for steel production, at least not by itself.

It depends on what phase of steel making you care about though. An electric arc furnace is most often use to melt down scrap, which you then purify (e.g. with the Basic Oxygen Process), then add whatever you need to get the alloy you want.

You seem to care about starting from ore though. In that case, you're starting from iron ore (e.g, taconite) which is almost always some form of iron oxide.

So, the main impurity you need to remove from iron ore to get iron is oxygen. In a traditional blast furnace, you use carbon not only as something to burn to get heat, but also as a chemical reactant.

Simplifying the chemical process involved<sup>1</sup>, you're basically doing FeO<sub>2</sub> + C => Fe + CO<sub>2</sub>. You do have to get the iron ore hot before the oxygen will unbind from the iron and bind to the carbon instead.

Regardless of the precise details of the chemical process, the main point is that you need to do more than just get iron ore hot. Rather, you need to heat the iron ore in an oxygen-deprived atmosphere in the presence of something else that will absorb the oxygen from the iron. Traditionally, carbon has been used for both the burning to produce heat and as the material that absorbs oxygen from the iron ore.

So, while it's obviously possible to get the iron ore hot with an electric furnace, you still need to add something to absorb the oxygen being released from the iron ore. Oxygen binds to lots of other materials, so there's no shortage of candidates. The difficulty tends to be that it binds fairly strongly to most other elements, so you frequently have to expend a lot of energy to get the element in reasonably pure (oxygen-free) form.

Hydrogen is attractive in this respect. Although it does consume energy, it's pretty easy to separate water into hydrogen and oxygen via electrolysis. In fact, you can do it at extremely small scale with a glass of water and a AA battery.

I'm not sure whether you care, but hydrogen does pose some pretty serious engineering problems of its own though:

1. even in liquid form, it's pretty low density, so you need large tanks of hydrogen to store enough to do much.
2. Designing hydrogen tanks is seriously non-trivial for at least a couple reasons:

   - many metals get brittle when exposed to reasonably pure hydrogen
   - hydrogen molecules are small enough that they leak through many materials

The difficulty here isn't really with finding elements that will combine with oxygen. The difficulty is much more with finding elements that combine with oxygen...gently enough, so to speak. If you wanted to use solely electricity, you could (for one example) purify buaxite (aluminum ore), which is normally done with an electrical process.

Then grind your aluminum into a fine powder, and heat alongside iron oxide. The oxygen will combine with the aluminum. The problem is that it does so rather...violently. The process is exceedingly exothermic--in fact, when you do this with a small quantity of iron oxide and aluminum, it's called a "thermite grenade". So while this works (in one respect) you'd need to do some pretty "special" engineering to keep it from destroying the furnace. It's not really a practical choice for steel production.

---

1. If memory serves, the real process happens in two steps. First, at relatively low temperature you get CO<sub>2</sub> + C => 2CO. Then at higher temperature you get: FeO<sub>2</sub> + 2CO => Fe + 2CO<sub>2</sub>. Caveat: I'm going from memory on the chemical reactions involved, so it's probably still a bit wrong. The real point isn't the precise reaction, but the fact that you're using the carbon not only as fuel, but also as a reactant, so replacing it means not only getting ore hot but using some other reactant as well.